# Encode URL without encoding forward slashes?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to encode a URL without encoding the forward slashes in ASP.net? I mainly want to encode it so that spaces in file names don't mess up a result string the users can share files with.

Comment: Encode it, and then replace the encoded forward slash with the char.

Comment: Looks like Server.UrlPathEncode is what I was looking for. :) w000t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Server.UrlPathEncode that us what it is for